# Confusion over different behavior of different directives in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am confused between the different behavior of different directives. In below code `ng-repeat` just takes a string but `ng-source` needs `image` to be an expression. Can someone explain?

```
<ul>
       <li ng-repeat = "image in product.images" >
                <img ng-src="{{image}}" />
       </li>
</ul>
```

To clarify more:
Why isn't the syntax for `ng-repeat` like:

`ng-repeat = "{{image in product.images}}"`

Comment: what problem you facing?

Comment: @PankajBadukale I have edited to make it clear. Pls have a look again.

Comment: `ng-src`, `ng-srcset`, and `ng-href` understand double curly bracket `{{` `}}` interpolation. All the others don't parse double curly brackets. Just one of the many quirks of AngularJS.

Comment: @georgeawg oh i see. Thanks :)

Comment: @georgeawg No, that's completely incorrect. The goal of these directives is to prevent the user to click on a link, or the browser to download the image, while the expression is not interpolated yet.

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the dynamic behaviour.
When you are using `ng-repeat`, you are iterating over a collection, which is pre-defined. Nothing dynamic about it. The value of variable itself can be dynamic, but you can rest assured that you'll iterate over same *variable*(or inline array  like `[1,2,3,4]`).

But when you are using `ng-src`, you are passing some dynamic path for that image. Angular will then add `src` attribute, when it resolves the value of `{{image}}`.

You should check out how we pass arguments for [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).
`<div ng-include="template.url"></div>`. Here `template.url` is **not** the actual path as you would expect src to have. Rather it is using a variable. In case you want to pass exact path, you would include it in `'` with exact path as string. e.g:

`<div class="slide-animate" ng-include="template_path+'template1.html'"></div>`.

Notice the `'template1.html'` enclosed in single quotes representing string, and template_path is a variable here.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed one of the pain points with AngularJS directives, that has been solved in Angular 2+: you need to carefully read the documentation of the directive (or its source code, if not well documented), to know what the directive expects.

Usually, when the value to pass is a string (like an image URL, or a link href), the directive doesn't expect you to pass an expression, and you can directly pass a static string using, for example, `ng-src="/images/foo.png"`. And if you want the value to be dynamic, like the value of a scope variable, you use interpolation: `ng-src="{{ imagePath }}"`.

If the directive expects a non-string value (like a boolean, or an object, or a specific micro-syntax like the one used by ng-repeat or ng-options), or when the directive expects that the value to pass is always dynamic, then you don't use interpolation, and the expression is always dynamic. Note that in that case, passing a literal string needs to be done this way: `foo="'static string'"`.

But it always boils down to the choice made in the design of the directive, and you need to read the documentation.